# For angular md-autocomplete i was not able to understand the following line can anyone explain

Tags: angularjs

var results = query ? self.states.filter(createFilterFor(query))
                : self.states, deferred;

Here is the link https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: Is there anything in particular you don't understand?  It's ternary operation which sets the value of results, it filters the results if query exits and simply returns the current unfiltered states if query isn't set and sets the variable deferred to undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know about the ternary operator. But I was not clear how the comma has come into picture for this line. Can you shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Var deffered is set everytime regardless of the outcome of the ternary funciton.  I did some testing in the console to prove this.

```
//Set ternary condition variable.
var test = true;
undefined
//check to see if newVal is set to anything, it returns an error because the variable doesn't exist yet.
newVal
VM1128:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: newVal is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM1128:1
//Try the ternary operation, it returns true.
var ans = test ? true: false, newVal;
undefined
//Was the newVal var created?  YES.
newVal
undefined
//Try setting it to a value.
var ans = test ? true: false, newVal = 50;
undefined
newVal
50
//And if the ternary operation returns false?
var test = false;
undefined
var ans = test ? true: false, newVal = 3;
undefined
newVal
3
```